# How do I solicit newer answers for an old question?

Tags: discussion, support, old-questions

I found a question that I was going to ask, but it is old, and the answers to it are old, too. I expect that the situation has changed and there are newer valid answers, but it doesn't look like the question is getting the attention anymore.

How do I solicit newer answers for an old question, short of asking it again?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: Offer a bounty?

Comment: Also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions